# Multivariate grouping - how to cluster/group elements with three attributes

Tags: clustering

I have three dimensional attributes: height, breadth, length for a large number of elements. I want to simply form groups of these elements based on these three variables, where I can further test hypothesis on these elements. The hypothesis will be of the kind: all elements in one group will have that or that color, then check samples for each group if this holds.

How would I go forward to group my elements? I would be extremely grateful if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: This is probably too broad to be answerable here. I don't see an answer beyond 'use cluster analysis', but you already have the `[clustering]` tag, so that probably won't be of value to you. Can you focus your question & make it more concrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have entered the wide-wide world of cluster analysis. Assuming you use R [this](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html) tutorial should teach you how to cluster your observations. Your three variables should be in the same scale since they are dimension measurements. However, you may still want to standardize them within each dimension (i.e. use z-scores). If the range of values for one dimension is larger than another it will dominate the clustering. However, depending on your specific goals, problem, etc. that may make sense.

K-means is the most popular method. Given your data have a very direct Euclidean space interpretation, the methodology of k-means makes a lot of sense. In terms of determining how many clusters you should find, that is the typically the great question mark of clustering. It is very subjective, but there are objective criteria. The site I linked to above will make an elbow plot for you. Hopefully there is a kink in it. The kink indicates where adding more clusters doesn't make much sense (i.e. adding more clusters doesn't account for much more variance).

After you have your clusters, you can save the cluster assignment as a column in your data and use regression on other variables to predict cluster assignment (or vice versa). You'd probably have to use [multinomial logistic regression](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/regressionMultinom.html) unless you have a sufficient number of clusters (lets say 7) and you can find some logical way of ordering them. That's unlikely though. If you can, than standard regression should give similar results with less work. Multinomial models are a bit tougher to work with than standard regression (I'm assuming you aren't already familiar), so make sure you do a lot of reading.